# Button Interaction Failed - Page System

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a Google search engine bot, which searches for an image using an API. I want to do a page system, but so far it is going horribly. The buttons won't even work!

```
       async function main(currentindex=0,embed=null,response_=null) {
            const keyword = message.content.split(' ')[1]
            const result = await fetch(url + keyword + rest, {
              method: 'GET'
            })
            console.log(currentindex)
            console.log(message)
            const json_Result = await result.json();
            embed = embed ?? new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(json_Result['images_results'][currentindex]['source'])
                .setDescription(json_Result['images_results'][currentindex]['link'])
                .addFields({name: '**Info**', value: json_Result['images_results'][currentindex]['title']})
                .setImage(json_Result['images_results'][currentindex]['thumbnail'])
            const previousButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setCustomId('previous')
                  .setLabel('PREVIOUS')
                  .setDisabled(currentindex > 0)
                  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            const nextButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setCustomId('next')
                  .setLabel('NEXT')
                  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
                  .addComponents(previousButton, nextButton)
            console.log(message.author)
            response_ = response_ ?? await message.reply({embeds: [embed], components: [row], allowedMentions: {repliedUser: false}})
            console.log(response_)
            const collectorFilter = i => i.user.id === message.author.id;
            const responser = await response_.awaitMessageComponent({ filter: collectorFilter})
            console.log(responser)
            if (responser.customId === 'next') {
                currentindex++;
                main(currentindex, embed, response_)
            } else if (responser.customId === 'previous') {
                currentindex--;
                main(currentindex, embed, response_)
            } else {
                console.log(response_)
            }
          }
```

Here's what happens when I try to click it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since `awaitMessageComponent()` returns a promise, you need to use `.then()` in order to receive the interaction. For example:

```js
responser.then(interaction => {
    if (interaction.customId == 'next') {
        currentIndex++
        main(currentindex, embed, response_)
    } else if (interaction.customId == 'previous') {
        currentIndex--
        main(currentindex, embed, response_)
    }
})
```